# How to download images from AWS into a folder in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, jszip

The following code *works*. But it only downloads one image. I want it to download several images and if not too much trouble to put them in a folder, maybe a zip folder. It will not download more than one photo for some reason (It says Network fail on the download on additional images). And I tried implementing JSZip, which I got set up but I could not figure out how to then use the new JSZip object to initiate a download from the server. Can anyone suggest some code or point me in the right direction?

Preferably I want it to happen on the server.

On the client:

```
'click #download-all-photos': function (event, template) {
  Files.find({
     productId: this._id
  }).forEach((photo) => {

    Meteor.call('get.s3.image', photo, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
           console.log(error);
        } else {

           function _arrayBufferToBase64(buffer) {
              var binary = '';
              var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
              var len = bytes.byteLength;
              for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                 binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i] );
              }
              return window.btoa(binary);
           }

           let base64 = _arrayBufferToBase64(result.data);

           base64 = 'data:' +result.mimeType+ ';base64,'+base64;

           let link = document.createElement('a');
           link.setAttribute('href', base64);
           link.setAttribute('download', result.fileName);
           link.click();
           link.remove();

        }
     });

  });

}

});
```

Server:

```
'get.s3.image': function (photo) {
  let fileType = '';
  let split = photo.url.split('.');
  fileType = split[split.length-1];

  let bucket = split[0].replace('https://', '');

  var s3 = new AWS.S3({
     accessKeyId: AWSAccessKeyId,
     secretAccessKey: AWSSecretAccessKey
  });

  let split2 = photo.url.split('/');
  let split3 = photo.url.split(split2[2] + '/');

  let fileName = '';
  fileName = split2[split2.length-1];

  let key = split3[1];

  let mimeType = mime.lookup(photo.url);

  let fut = new Future();

  s3.getObject(
     { Bucket: bucket, Key: key },
     function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
           console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
           fut['return'](error);
           throw new Meteor.Error('500', error);
        } else {
           console.log("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");

           fut['return']({
              mimeType: mimeType,
              fileName: fileName,
              data: data.Body
           });

        }
     }
  );

  return fut.wait();
},
```

Another thing I tried was making a route that downloads the image. Again it works, but I can only get it to do one image. I would rather it loop through a queried collection of images and download them all into a zip folder:

```
Router.route('/download_file/:_id', {
name: 'download.file',
where: 'server',
action: function () {
  let res = this.response;

  let image = Files.findOne(this.params._id);

  if (!image) {
     res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
     res.end('404: No Images Found');
     return;
  }

  let mimeType = mime.lookup(image.url);

  let fileType = '';
  let split = image.url.split('.');

  fileType = split[split.length-1];
  let bucket = split[0].replace('https://', '');

  var s3 = new AWS.S3({
     accessKeyId: AWSAccessKeyId,
     secretAccessKey: AWSSecretAccessKey
  });

  let split2 = image.url.split('/');
  let split3 = image.url.split(split2[2] + '/');

  let key = split3[1];

  s3.getObject(
     { Bucket: bucket, Key: key },
     function (error, data) {
        if (error != null) {
           console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
        } else {
           let headers = {
              'Content-Type': mimeType,
              'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=file."+fileType
           };
           res.writeHead(200, headers);
           res.end(data.Body, 'binary');
        }
     }
  );
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved my own problem! Maybe kinda hacky. I got JSZip working. It gets the files from S3 then sends them to the client to be downloaded into a zip (downloaded via `saveAs()` from a meteor package). Seems to work really well. Maybe this can help someone else.

Client:

```
'click #download-all-photos': function (event, template) {

  let JSZip = require('jszip');

  let zip = new JSZip();
  let folder = zip.folder('photos');

  let hasError = false;

  let fileName = '';
  if (this.mpn) fileName += this.mpn + '_';
  fileName += this.productNumber;

  let count = 0;
  let number = Files.find({ productId: this._id }).count();

  let downloaded = false;

  Files.find({ productId: this._id }).forEach((photo) => {

     Meteor.call('get.s3.image', photo, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
           console.log(error);
        } else {
           folder.file(result.fileName, result.data);

           count++;

           if (count === number && !downloaded) {

              downloaded = true;

              let zipFile = zip.generate();

              let base64 = 'data:application/zip;base64,'+zipFile;

              fetch(base64)
                 .then(res => res.blob())
                 .then(blob => {
                    saveAs(blob, fileName + '.zip');
                 });

           }

        }
     });

  });

}
```

Server:

```
'get.s3.image': function (photo) {
  let fileType = '';
  let split = photo.url.split('.');
  fileType = split[split.length-1];

  let bucket = split[0].replace('https://', '');

  var s3 = new AWS.S3({
     accessKeyId: AWSAccessKeyId,
     secretAccessKey: AWSSecretAccessKey
  });

  let split2 = photo.url.split('/');
  let split3 = photo.url.split(split2[2] + '/');

  let fileName = '';
  fileName = split2[split2.length-1];

  let key = split3[1];

  let mimeType = mime.lookup(photo.url);

  let fut = new Future();

  s3.getObject(
     { Bucket: bucket, Key: key },
     function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
           console.log("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
           fut['return'](error);
           throw new Meteor.Error('500', error);
        } else {
           console.log("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");

           fut['return']({
              mimeType: mimeType,
              fileName: fileName,
              data: data.Body
           });

        }
     }
  );

  return fut.wait();
},
```